Intergrating Easy Anti Cheat - Do we need to add Epic login?
We plan to add Easy Anti Cheat to our Steam game.
One of our managers said that we need to integrate Epic login for EAC to work.
Is this true?
We couldnt find any mentions of this in Epic EAC docs.
(We already have our own account system, if this matters, and we don't plan to use any other EOS services except EAC)

EAC requires some way to identify the user/client to do its job.
The EOS_AntiCheatClient_BeginSessionOptions structure requires a user ID, which is acquired from logging in to EOS successfully.

LocalUserId
Logged in user identifier from earlier call to EOS_Connect_Login family of functions

The EOS login can be done with a device ID instead of requiring the user to log in with their Epic account. See EOS_Connect_CreateDeviceId.

Create a new unique pseudo-account that can be used to identify the current user profile on the local device. This function is intended to be used by mobile games and PC games that wish to allow a new user to start playing without requiring to login to the game using any user identity.


I would also like to bring light to the fact that Easy Anti-Cheat has gone through lots of compatibility problems with Steam Deck (i.e. Proton on Linux) so if you care about that user base please take a minute to learn about their EAC issues and try to avoid replicating them.

Thank you for info about EAC compatibility with Steam Deck!
